# HttpClient does not exist in .net 4.0: what can I do?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Ok i edited my code i dont get errors but the messageBox.Show return nothing empty box.
Maybe i need to add something in the referrer string ? I didnt understand what is the referrer and what should i put there. And i have a key already im using it in my code.
The key is a long string and im using it in my code i dont use with the referrer. Why it dosent translate the word "hi" ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;




namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private JavaScriptSerializer _Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string f = TranslateText("hi", "English", "German", "", "");
            MessageBox.Show(f);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public string TranslateText(string inputText, string sourceLanguage, string destinationLanguage, string referrer, string apiKey)
        {
                string requestUrl = string.Format(
                    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q={0}&langpair={1}|{2}&key={3}", 
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inputText), 
                    sourceLanguage.ToLowerInvariant(), 
                    destinationLanguage.ToLowerInvariant(), 
                    apiKey
                );

                try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
                    http.Referer = referrer;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse();
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string responseJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        var translation = this._Serializer.Deserialize<Milkshake.Integration.Google.GoogleAjaxResponse<Milkshake.Integration.Google.Translate.TranslationResponse>>(responseJson);

                        if (translation != null && translation.ResponseData != null && translation.ResponseData.ResponseStatus == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            return translation.ResponseData.TranslatedText;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return String.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                }
            catch
                {
                    return String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The title of this question is very clear, but the question itself is unclear. Admittedly it shows research effort, but that's all. There should be at least a sentence of context instead of letting the reader figuring out. I saw you edited your own question, you should again but make sure the end result is readable for a newcomer. Questions do have value on the long run, but participants have to make it possible.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

- You can use [**WebClient**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).
- Or (if you need more fine-grained control over the request) [**HttpWebRequest**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)
- Or, [**HttpClient**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in System.Net.Http.dll.

Here's a "translation" to HttpWebRequest (needed rather than WebClient in order to set the referrer).  (Uses System.Net and System.IO):

```
    HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl))
    http.Referer = referrer;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse )http.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string responseJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
        // more stuff
    }
```

Comment: dbasdeman i know this WebClient and httpwebrequest but i dont know how to use it in my code instead the httpclient...can you show me how to do it in my code ? Thanks.

Comment: System.Web.Http is for .net 4.5 i have 4.0 im using visual studio csharp pro 2010 and i dont have .net 4.5

Comment: I edited my code. No errors but the translation dosent work yet.

Comment: For those of us still on .NET 4.0, there is an implementation of `HttpClient` I've just learned about that you can install using NuGet at http://nuget.org/packages/HttpClient - See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11615955/110871

Comment: Hmm, I may have commented too quickly; another answer on this page from @cecilphillip says the same thing, but links to a different NuGet package. So... be sure to figure out which one to use!

Comment: @Funka The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: System.Net.Http does not work for Net Framework 4.0!

Answer (score 85):

I've used HttpClient in .NET 4.0 applications on numerous occasions. If you are familiar with NuGet, you can do an Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http to add it to your project. See the link below for further details.

http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

Comment: yea... for mono you could use HttpWebRequest

Comment: It also says "This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010, and is only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5". Do you know what the difference is between this package, and http://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClient ?

Comment: I know that HttpClinet you're linking to was pre RTM and isn't being worked on any more. I used HttpClient in a few .NET 4.0 apps. I'm really not sure why that verbiage is there

Comment: I've used `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.30506`

Comment: For VS2010 the right version to use is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.0.20710

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.30506`worked for me with **Visual Studio 2013** and **Framework 4.0**

Answer (score 19):

Referring to the answers above, I am only adding this to help clarify things.  It is possible to use HttpClient from .Net 4.0, and you have to install the package from [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/)

However, the text is very confusion and contradicts itself.

> This package is not supported in Visual Studio 2010, and is only required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, or Windows Phone 8.1 when consuming a library that uses this package.

But underneath it states that these are the supported platforms.

Supported Platforms:

- .NET Framework 4
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1
- Windows Phone Silverlight 7.5
- Silverlight 4
- Portable Class Libraries

Ignore what it ways about targeting .Net 4.5.  This is wrong.  The package is all about using HttpClient in .Net 4.0.  However, you may need to use VS2012 or higher. Not sure if it works in VS2010, but that may be worth testing.

Comment: Using the link you provided, I was able to get my project to finally build!  Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 2):

read this...

**Portable HttpClient for .NET Framework and Windows Phone**

see paragraph *Using HttpClient on .NET Framework 4.0 or Windows Phone 7.5*
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with TrueWill's comment on a separate answer, the best way I've seen to use system.web.http on a .NET 4 targeted project under current Visual Studio is `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.30506`