# .Net 4.0 HttpClient usage?

Tags: .net, api, dotnet-httpclient

im in .Net 4.0 and attempting to use the HttpClient. I read some articles saying that it was no longer supported in 4.0 but that you could still use it? i've included the `System.Net.Http;` assembly but it's not allowing me to provide the necessary params to the `HttpClient`. Any idea how I could fix this?

I've bolded where the errors are occuring.

```
using (HttpClient http = new **HttpClient("{0}/v1/dm/labels/{1}.xml", MI_API_URL**))
        {
            http.**TransportSettings**.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(apiusername, apipassword);

            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parms = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            parms.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Status", "Wiped"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = http.**Get**(new Uri("devices.xml", UriKind.Relative), parms);
            response.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();
            responseoutput = response.Content.ReadAsString();
            xdoc.LoadXml(responseoutput);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per MSDN HttpClient is supported only in .NET Framework 4.5. Nevertheless there is an implementation of HttpClient for .NET 4.0. You can download it here:

[HttpClient for .NET 4.0](http://nuget.org/packages/HttpClient)

[MSDN: HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Still there are some differences in implementations. For example in version for .NET 4.0 there is no constructor w/ 2 parameters. Please see the source code for more information:

[HttpClient for .NET 4.0 source code](http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/417c9a96fc24#WCFWebApi/Http/Src/Microsoft.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs)

Regarding your example:

- There is no constructor w/ 2 params in impl. for .NET 4.0
- There is no Get method w/ 2 params in impl. for .NET 4.0
- There is no TransportSettings property in impl. for .NET 4.0

Comment: Thankyou Raman, this is what i suspected. I grabbed the dll using nuget

Comment: The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore. Use this instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http