# redirecting to page from inside iframe

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, iframe

I have just now started coding in .NET framework, so my apologies if this issue happens to be of trivial nature.

**What I got now**

A `main.aspx` page with simple layout using three `iframe`s

[image]

the middle iframe content needs to be dynamic (first a `login.aspx` page and after logging `entryform.aspx`)

---

**Issue #1** :

After logging in *login.aspx* inside the iframe, redirecting to *main.aspx*

**The solution I found**:

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"scriptid",
"window.parent.location.href='main.aspx'", true);`

(http://forums.asp.net/t/1273497.aspx)

---

**Issue #2**

After redirecting/logging how do I change the middle iframe content from *login.aspx*  to *entryform.aspx*?

**The silly solution I thought of**:

Add  *'#form'* to the url and listen to `hashchange` event in *main.aspx*. But then, anyone can get to the form using the url itself.

---

So, basically how do I find a secure way to tell the *main.aspx* page that it needs to change it's middle iframe content after the redirecting/logging

Or by any chance there is a *request.setAttribute and getAttribute* in .NET like in java that I have missed and made things difficult for me?

Comment: The layout will be modified later to include contents from one other website & some other documents from the server, i.e why I chose iframe for layout

Comment: Do these sites all reside on the same domain? Are they all ASP.NET?

Comment: nope not same domain, they are jsp pages with struts framework, somewhat like a webservice too

Comment: Okay, one more and I should be able to give you an example: how familiar are you with how authentication works in ASP.NET, and is FormsAuthentication acceptable? I assume the ASP.NET app drives the "middle frame"?

Comment: @TiesonT. I am not familiar with form authentication, but I will learn happily, even if you can give me references, I will study them fully, I want to do this properly. so pls do point me to the right direction

Comment: Start here, while I put something together (this isn't an easy question to answer quickly): http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security - most, if not all, of those articles were written by Scott Mitchell, and while they're a bit dated, the general concepts are valid. If you need more input before then, let's chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36681/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-rps)

Comment: If only middle frame needs to be dynamic, why do you redirect the parent and not just iframe itself, while keeping header and footer the same?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter This is just a simple layout, I will have other sections that will change accordingly later, I need to redirect to the page in those cases and I will be using layout templates to change the layout correspondingly in the page too or to a different page but either way I will have to set request params and not pass them in url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding that the use of iframe isn't exactly the best idea in my case, I took [Tieson T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534109/tieson-t)'s advice and  looked into [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) to fetch content from other web pages. In my case it will be both from same domain and other domains.

Since I have 4.0v .NET instead of [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) I used [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

**code**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (http://localhost:1706/WebSite3/test.html);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),encode );
string html= reader.ReadToEnd();
myDiv.innerHtml(html);
```

**References**

- [HttpClient does not exist in .net 4.0: what can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308572/httpclient-does-not-exist-in-net-4-0-what-can-i-do)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1382935.aspx/1
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx

Comment: Since you're doing this all on the server, it seems like it also has the benefit of giving you a higher degree of control over the content that the user eventually interacts with; dealing with iframes, you're relying on the client's browser to behave the way you expect. Nice work. Don't forget that you can accept your own answer (it helps imply that the question has been resolved, but doesn't prevent someone from adding a new answer in the future).

Comment: @TiesonT., about marking an answer, you post your suggestion, I will mark that as the answer only. I didn't ask for codes but for someone to point me to the right direction, you did that, not me myself :)

Answer (score 2):

Passing variables or values across pages and domains wont be issue, you can use post method and cross page posting for that

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just pass a parameter to Main.aspx? E.g.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"scriptid", "window.parent.location.href='main.aspx?LoadEntry=true'", true);
```

And client-side JavaScript code inside of 'main.aspx' would read that parameter from 'location.search' and if 'LoadEntry=true' is set - would set SRC of middle frame to "entryform.aspx".

Of course inside of "entryform.aspx.cs" you would need to check if correct login really took place (e.g. some Session variable is set) so nobody would be able to simple set URL manually to "main.aspx?LoadEntry=true" to bypass the login.

Comment: yea I had used FormAuthentication for that as Tieson suggested, It also worked. but in the long run I will be doing a lot of redirecting and intead of showing an authentication failed message and all I just thought instead of iframes using divs will be good