# RouteCollection' doesn't contain a definition for 'MapMvcAttributeRoutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reference, asp.net-mvc-routing

I just had to downgrade my **ASP.Net 4.5.2** application to **ASP.Net 4.0.** Of course this brings problems with it, like references that are not installed correct. I solved some of them already, but I can't get my head around an error:

> **CS106 'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for**
>   **'MapMvcAttributeRoutes' and no extension method**
>   **'MapMvcAttributeRoutes' accepting a first argument of type**
>   **'RouteCollection' could be found**

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "device", action = "view", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
```

Does someone know what I have to do here?

**Extra info**

Namespaces that I use:

- **using System.Web**
- **using System.Web.Mvc**
- **using System.Web.Routing**
- **using System.Web.Http**

Visual studio Community 2015

Answer (score 6):

The only version of MVC that supports attribute routing (which provides support for the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` extension method) is **MVC 5**.

However, [**MVC 5 *only* supports .NET framework 4.5**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385785/can-i-run-mvc-5-application-on-net-framework-4-0) and higher.

So, you have 2 options:

1. Stay on .NET Framework 4.5+
2. Downgrade to MVC 4 and either:

   1. Ditch attribute routing altogether and use convention-based routing
   2. Go with the open source [attribute routing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/) that supported MVC 3 and 4

> Being that Microsoft **[officially no longer supports any version of .NET Framework lower than 4.5.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/)** (except for 3.5, but that would mean downgrading to MVC 2 for support), I would highly recommend you consider the first option seriously.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) May I refer you to a previous question from me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968029/missing-namespaces-when-downgrading-to-asp-net-4-0

Answer (score 0):

I used routes.Ignore(). It seems to be working.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "device", action = "view", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```