# 'RouteCollection' doesn't contain a definition for 'MapMvcAttributeRoutes'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to use attribute based routing. But when i try the following snippet to activate attribute based routing i get the following error message:

> RouteCollection' doesn't contain a definition for
>   'MapMvcAttributeRoutes

This is my code:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //Attribute Routing
    }

}
```

These are the references:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

Thre Framework version for my project is **4.5.2**.

Whats wrong here and how i fix this?

Comment: What version of mvc are you using? see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991768/routecollection-doesnt-contain-a-definition-for-mapmvcattributeroutes

Comment: Its 4.0.0.1/Runtimeversion v4.0.30319. When i create a new project i select > create an empty ASP.NET 4.5.2 project within Visual Studio. – STORM 1 min ago    edit

Comment: `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` is only available from MVC5+

Comment: Can i create under Visual Studio an empty ASP.NET 4.5.2 project and add MVC5 to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it work now. I did the following:

I added first a new folder called `App_Start`. Within this folder i created a new class file named `RouteConfig.cs`.

The following code was added to the file above:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //Attribute Routing
    }
```

The i added a global.asax file to my project with the following code in `Application_Start` method:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Then under Extras > NuGet Package Manager > Pacakge Manager Console i added the [Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/) package to my project.

Finally i added a new MVC5 Empty controller with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("products")]
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        [Route]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("It Works!");

            //return View();
        }
    }
}
```

After this i was able to open my project in the project by typing:

```
http://localhost:65311/products
```