# 'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapRoute' and no accessible extension method 'MapRoute'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am a beginner to .NET. And I have looked at the several other posts with similar titles asked before. I tried these suggestions (As described below) but didn't help.

I need to use a project built by someone else to test a functionality.

When I build the project I get these two errors.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'IgnoreRoute' and no accessible extension method 'IgnoreRoute'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'RouteCollection' could be found

.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'MapRoute' and no accessible extension method 'MapRoute' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'RouteCollection' could be found

The offending code is this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace DocumentConverterWebAPI
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

First I read this post.
[RouteCollection' doesn't contain a definition for 'MapMvcAttributeRoutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991768/routecollection-doesnt-contain-a-definition-for-mapmvcattributeroutes)

The most voted answer states that this is because it requires .NET version 4.5+ and the OP has 4.0 something.

Next I wanted to check the .NET version installed in my machine.
In developer command prompt

```
clrver

Microsoft (R) .NET CLR Version Tool  Version 4.6.1055.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Versions installed on the machine:
v4.0.30319
```

It seems I have an 4.0 version.

But when I try to install .NET 4.5.2 I get this error.

[image]

I ran the .NET Framework verification utility and it says that 4.5.2 is installed properly.

[image]

Project target framework is set to 4.5.2

[image]

This post suggests that this might be because of Resharper plugin.
[MapRoute and IgnoreRoute Up and Vanished RSS](https://forums.asp.net/t/1290354.aspx?MapRoute%20and%20IgnoreRoute%20Up%20and%20Vanished)

So, I disabled resharper but the errors were still there.

EDITS
Screenshots show when I tried installing 4.5.2 version of .NET

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850322/routecollection-doesnt-contain-a-definition-for-mapmvcattributeroutes

Comment: @S.Akbari I did check this post earlier. The OP himself has given the answer and haven't given any explanation for what he did. And I'm bit hesitant to change the code unless I understand why. Also the project did work successfully when I tested on a mac yesterday. (With Resharper IDE)

Comment: You are showing Net 4.5.2 while the Project is set to 4.7.2.  Not all Net libraries are part of each version of Net.  You need to have all previous version installed to make sure you have all the libraries.  The link S.Akbari provided the OP installed Net 4.5.2 using the link on the posting.  I think you should install Net 4.5.2.

Comment: @jdweng 4.5.2 is already installed. I checked with verifier tool. Sorry for the wrong screenshot above. I'll update the question.

Comment: Is Net 3.5 installed?  I went to Microsoft Reference which has the source code for the c# and it looks like IgnoreRoute is part of Net 3.5.

Comment: @jdweng It was not installed. But I installed it now. Does't seems to make any difference.    https://imgur.com/a/Av0tqTM

Comment: See msdn blog : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/