# Windows Forms Application with Microsoft Graph API functionality

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am interested in developing a Windows Forms application that periodically checks if my database has new entrances for a table that abstracts event scheduling.
If new events have been added to the database, my application should get those events and post them to the Office 365 Calendar.

I've been researching for a while and have not found a proper way to call Microsoft Graph API services from within a Windows Forms application.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: The version I'm using is v4.0.30319 @MarcLaFleur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Microsoft Graph .Net Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) available but you will first need to upgrade the version of .NET you're currently targeting to at least `v4.5`.

Alternatively, you can call into Microsoft Graph using either `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`. This will require you to construct all your calls and handle serialization/deserialization on your own however. You can find some additional details in this answer as well: [HttpClient does not exist in .net 4.0: what can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308572/httpclient-does-not-exist-in-net-4-0-what-can-i-do/10308597#10308597)

My guidance would be that unless you're very familiar with HTTP and Serialization, I would focus on upgrading your .NET target and use the SDK. Hand-crafting REST and OAUTH calls is typically not a very enjoyable experience.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed information on the issue options. But responding to my question, is it possible to call every service from a windows forms app? How would you go about the token authentication process on such an app?

Comment: What do you mean by "every service"?

Comment: Since the Graph API uses JSON over REST, there is no reason that you can't access every service from a Windows Forms app with .NET 4.0. But if you want to use the existing client libraries, which do all the dirty work for you, you need to upgrade to .NET 4.5.

Comment: I need to post events to Office365. Can I perform that service in my application? @MarcLaFleur

Comment: If you want to add Events to an Outlook/Exchange Calendar, Microsoft Graph can handle that yes.

Comment: Last question. Do you know if it's possible to add Events to several accounts using my native application? I would have permissions from all the accounts. @MarcLaFleur

Comment: As long as you have permission then yes.