# It's possible to use Computer Vision API with VS2010?

Tags: .net, azure-cognitive-services

I am newbie to the development of Cognitive service and I want to know if it is possible to use Computer Vision API with visual studio 2010 (NET 4.0)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are REST APIs, so absolutely you can use older tools.  You cannot, however, use the NuGet-hosted [client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision/) as these require new version of the framework.  So you would need to find another compatible library, or handcraft your own web requests.

You might also consider getting a newer version of the IDE, some of which are even free of charge.  See [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use samples from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp in VS with your .NET version.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308572/httpclient-does-not-exist-in-net-4-0-what-can-i-do) for some additional notes regarding this suggestion.